# Выдаёт ответ от POST запроса, а не саму страницу

Tags: php, curl

У меня выдаёт не то, что мне нужно.
В начале грузится страница, создаётся файл с cookies.

Затем выбирается нужный токен для последующего POST запроса.

Функцией отправляется POST запрос, в ответ мне приходит ответ от сервера, т.е. response (в firebug такой же ответ от сервера), но почему то саму страницу не показывает. Обычно когда делаешь настройки curl, то потом просто обычный echo и имя переменной и всё выводит `($b = curl_exec($curl); echo $b)`, а тут выводит постоянно ответ от POST запроса, а не саму страницу...

**Как вывести саму страницу после авторизации?**

```
<?PHP
$logpass = "Zyavr@mail.ru";
$curl = curl_init();
LoadPage($curl, "https://example.lnk/");
curl_close($curl);

$file = file('cook.txt');
$a = substr($file[5], 40, -1);  // возвращает чистый token

$curl = curl_init();
$Post = array(
    'token' =>  $a,
    'login' => $logpass,
    'op' => 'login',
    'password' => $logpass
);
$header = array(
            "Referer: https://example.lnk/?op=home",
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0",
            "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
            "x-token: ".$a
            );
print_r(LoadPage($curl, "https://example.lnk/", $Post, $header, $dop=1));
curl_close($curl);
function LoadPage($curl, $url, $post = 0, $headers = 0, $dop = 0)
{
    $user_cookies = "cook.txt";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookies); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookies);
    if($post!=0)
    {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    }
    if($headers!=0)
    {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookies); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookies);

    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    if($dop!=0)
    {
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Вот что возвращает сервер:

```
s1:1b9rNY88337a2gZM3oqLrThv4LxMArkU6:4bf32d6bc46bbe4f4bbd09408517be3db88bbd2456f326359f01efcad977ce50:1515489
```

Comment: Так может так и задумывалось? Вы указываете, что ваш запрос ajax, зачем серверу страницу отдавать вам?

Comment: Хорошо, ладно, допустим, что задумывалось. Делаю третий запрос через функцию и опять же возвращается тот ответ от POST запроса.

Comment: Покажите, что именно вам возвращает сервер.

Comment: Добавил в самом конце, что возвращает сервер

Comment: Третий запрос у вас аналогичен 1му или 2му (post)?